# Rust: cannot find macro

Tags: import, rust, macros, rust-macros

I'm trying to run rust code from the `postgres_types` documentation.

The example code can be found here: [postgres_types](https://docs.rs/crate/postgres-types/0.1.0-alpha.1)

my rust environment:

> cargo --version
>   cargo 1.40.0-nightly (5da4b4d47 2019-10-28)
>
> rustc --version
>   rustc 1.40.0-nightly (b520af6fd 2019-11-03)

---

main.rs

```
#[cfg(feature = "derive")]
use postgres_types::{ToSql, FromSql};

#[derive(Debug, ToSql, FromSql)]
enum Mood {
    Sad,
    Ok,
    Happy,
}

fn main() {
    let mood = Mood::Sad;

    println!("{:?}", mood);
}
```

---

Cargo.toml

```
...

[dependencies]
postgres-types = "0.1.0-alpha.1"
```

---

When I try and run with `cargo run` I get:

```
error: cannot find derive macro `ToSql` in this scope
 --> src\main.rs:4:17
  |
4 | #[derive(Debug, ToSql, FromSql)]
  |                 ^^^^^

error: cannot find derive macro `FromSql` in this scope
 --> src\main.rs:4:24
  |
4 | #[derive(Debug, ToSql, FromSql)]
  |                        ^^^^^^^
```

What am I doing wrong here? Clearly I'm missing something basic. Have I not imported the macro correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from the documentation,

> If the `derive` cargo feature is enabled, you can derive ToSql and FromSql implementations for custom Postgres types.

To enable the `derive` feature, you'll need to put this in `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
postgres-types = {version = "0.1.0-alpha.1", features = ["derive"]}
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the dependencies as required and I removed `#[cfg(feature = "derive")]` from main.rs and it worked! It's great that it's working, but I admit I don't completely understand the mechanism

Comment: @JamesSchinner You can learn more about features in the [Cargo manifest documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section).

Comment: To complement this answer: Make sure you then import `FromSql` and `ToSql` from `postgres_types::{FromSql, ToSql};` and not the reexported version from `postgresql`.